# Problems with UPDATE profile user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with updating user profiles. Whenever I updated all information such as `name` . `email`, `phone`  and `password`. They all appeared on the profile page with the updated information but whenever I tried to login with new email. It said no such email within the database. It turned out that the original email from UID in Authentication haven't changed and when I tried logging in with original email,it worked.

Another problem is whenever I tried to update the profile, the whole information disappears which I have no idea how to fix that.

Update.java

```
public class Update extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("users");
    String userID;
    Button Update, Cancel;
    EditText NewName,NewEmail,NewPhoneNumber,NewPassword;
    String _NewName, _NewEmail,_NewPhoneNumber,_NewPassword;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();

        NewName = findViewById(R.id.newname);
        NewPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.newphonenumber);
        NewEmail = findViewById(R.id.newemail);
        NewPassword = findViewById(R.id.newpassword);

        String email = NewEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = NewPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String name = NewName.getText().toString();
        String phone =NewPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

        HashMap<String , String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("name",name);
        userMap.put("email",email);
        userMap.put("phone",phone);
        userMap.put("password",password);

        root.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(userMap);

        root.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                users userProfile = snapshot.getValue(users.class);

                if(userProfile != null){
                    String name = userProfile.name;
                    String email = userProfile.email;
                    String phone = userProfile.phone;
                    String password = userProfile.password;


                    NewName.setText(name);
                    NewEmail.setText(email);
                    NewPhoneNumber.setText(phone);
                    NewPassword.setText(password);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Update.this,"Something wrong happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Update = findViewById(R.id.buttonupdate);

        Update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = NewEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = NewPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String name = NewName.getText().toString();
                String phone =NewPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

                HashMap<String , String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                userMap.put("name",name);
                userMap.put("email",email);
                userMap.put("phone",phone);
                userMap.put("password",password);

                root.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(userMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                        Toast.makeText(Update.this,"Your Data is Successfully Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        Cancel = findViewById(R.id.buttoncancel);

        Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Profile Activity.java

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseUser user;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    String userID;

    Button MainMenu,Logout,UpdatePage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        userID = user.getUid();

        final TextView ViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        final TextView ViewEmail = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.Email);
        final TextView ViewPhonenumber = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.Phonenumber);

        reference.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                users userProfile = snapshot.getValue(users.class);

                if(userProfile != null){
                    String name = userProfile.name;
                    String email = userProfile.email;
                    String phonenumber = userProfile.phone;


                    ViewName.setText(name);
                    ViewEmail.setText(email);
                    ViewPhonenumber.setText(phonenumber);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Something wrong happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        UpdatePage = findViewById(R.id.updatepage);

        UpdatePage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Update.class));
            }
        });


        Logout = findViewById(R.id.Logoutbutton);

        Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
            }
        });

        MainMenu = findViewById(R.id.Mainbtn);

        MainMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: 1. Whenever I updated email to another new email. That new email is invalid to use when logging.
2. Whenever I go to update page, whole information disappear in database.

Comment: I see, but can you please share the piece of code where you're actually updating the email?

Comment: I think you can see the update part at `Update.java` above.

Comment: Are you reffering to this line `root.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(userMap);`?

Comment: Yes. I think that's also a part of the problems why my code acts weird.

Comment: "I think" doesn't help. Please indicate the exact lines of code where you perform the email update.

Comment: It should be this  `String email = NewEmail.getText().toString().trim();`  and `userMap.put("email",email);` inside of HashMap  in  `Update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` inside of Update.java.` Where these are needed to update.

Comment: That's no update operation, most likely that's the reason why you get the behavior.